# Parameterise super class with class member of mixin class

Tags: scala, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, mixins

```
trait Mixin {
    class P
}

abstract class SuperClass[T]

class Impl extends SuperClass[P] with Mixin
```

Gives:

```
not found: type P
```

Is there any way to provide the member class `P` which is mixed in as the parameter to a super class, or is this impossible because of ordering of evaluation (or some other problem?).

Comment: What would you expect `P` to be here? `Mixin#P`? Not sure I follow.

Comment: The use case is a Slick schema. `P` is subclass of `Table`. `P` has to be defined within the context of a class such that imports can be correctly defined so Slick can work with a given "profile".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way the scopes don't work out correctly. But type members and type parameters are nearly equivalent, and if you can make `T` a member of `SuperClass` instead, you get

```
abstract class SuperClass {
  type T
}
// optional
object SuperClass {
  type Aux[T0] = SuperClass { type T = T0 }
}

class Impl extends SuperClass with Mixin {
  type T = P
}
```

In those cases where you want `T` to be used as a generic parameter, you use `SuperClass.Aux[T]`.